# Corporate website, each page different style

Tags: theming, 7

I need to create a corporate business website under Drupal 7, and on each page (home, about, sevices, contact, etc.) the design is really different.

What would be the best way to structure/build this in Drupal? I'm used to Wordpress theme per page, but this does not look like it's built in Drupal.

Like thi theme: http://demo.drupalizing.com/?theme=corporateclean
http://drupal.org/project/corporateclean

The design change quite a bit for each page. But when I download the theme, I don't see how they did that, since there's only that general page...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new theme using one of the many starter themes, and then override templates to get as specific as you please.

For example, to override a particular content type's look, you'd edit node--contenttype.tpl.php where contenttype is your custome content type.

[The template guide](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) contains further info, including naming conventions to get your templates applied in the right place.

Comment: Thats a very informative finding.

Answer (score 1):

In such case what I do is: I write the following code in my template.php of the theme

```
function themename_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

     if (isset($vars['node']->type)) {

     $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $vars['node']->type;

 }
    }
```

Then I create a page.tpl.php for each content-type. For example if it is for content-type hotnews, then I create a page--hotnews.tpl.php file in my templates folder. In page--hotnews.tpl.php I write  the things that I want to appear in my hotnews page.

For the front page, I create page--front.tpl.php. And I write  the things like menu, header and footer that are common in all pages, in html.tpl.php.